# RSS Count doesn't appear unless I alert a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, alert, jquery-mobile

I'm implementing a jquery mobile site and I've hit a snag when trying to show a count of RSS feeds using  `class="ui-li-count"`

I'm able to pull the number from my script but it will not alert or display in the `class="ui-li-count"` unless I alert a string first.

For example:

The span I am trying to add my count to - `<span id="rsscount" class="ui-li-count"></span>`

Code that neither alerts or displays the count:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert(feedcount);
            $('#rsscount').html(feedcount); 
        });
    </script>
```

Code that both alerts the number **and** properly display the count inside my span *after I dismiss the alert*:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("3");
            $('#rsscount').html(feedcount);
        });
    </script>
```

I am using ZrssFeed to get the feed. Any idea what that alert string does to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`feedcount` appears to be undefined

You are probably defining it in response to some Ajax event firing.

`document.ready` almost certainly fires before the HTTP request to trigger that event comes back.

Move the call to `html()` to the callback for the Ajax request.

Comment: This makes sense, and sorry for being a rookie here, but since JQM is doing alot of this behind the scenes I'm not sure I can move the html() call to the AJAX request. Any pointers?

Comment: Dorward I moved the call into a timeout() for 5 seconds and it's working (thanks!), but there is probably a better way to do this.

Comment: dude... don't do that! put the `.html` thing in a callback of AJAX call. the AJAX call should be wrapped in DOM ready event, not this.

Comment: Also, to prevent you further - if you are using javascript codes put in a body of a page that JQM loads via ajax, then don't. Remove it and put in `pageshow` or `pagecreate` events in the main page or in a .js linked to every page